# NIFI:Using RouteOnContent for filtering responses?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to  use  routeonContent and  put  my response  in deifferenct directories  based on  the method  names  they consist  i  have attribute '$message.body' and  use expression(  in  routeonContent) `${message.body:contains('<person>')}` . But it  doesn't  work   for me  do  you have  any better  idea  how can i do  this?

Comment: I  need  to  check  if  it  conatains  tag  with  name  person and  if  it  does  o will  route it  to certian   direction

Comment: I have  replaced ${message.body:contains('<person>')}  with this ${message.body:contains("<[^>][+ person+^>]*>")} but it  still  doesn't  works

Answer (score 0):

if you want to route based on attribute value then you need `RouteOnAttribute` processor

Comment: the `RouteOnContent` tests the content of the flow file and not the attribute.

Comment: can  i use regex  like this  inside  routeOnAttribute ${message.body:contains("<[^>][+ person+^>]*>")} all  the   tiem i  use  it , processor  puts  flowfile into unmatche  connection

Comment: for `RouteOnContent` just set `Match Requirement = content must contain match` and `PERSON = <person>`. or instead of `<person>` you can set regular expression.